# Get astropy .fits file column data from unique ID in another column

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I'm trying to retrieve data from an [astropy fits file](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/), in Python, where the data from lots of unique ID objects have been collated into a continuous record.

By this I mean the .fits file has shape: (25603520,)

I would like to get all the data from the *rows* where the ID is preselected. E.g. for the .fits file below, I would like to get all 5 columns worth of data for the *rows* who's first column value is: 'NGTSJ225342.6+015412'.

```
  FITS_rec([('NGTSJ225342.6+015412', 2457881.8909375 ,  85.15793 , 10.182051, 0),
          ('NGTSJ225342.6+015412', 2457881.89107639, 109.891716, 10.210967, 0),
          ('NGTSJ225342.6+015412', 2457881.89122685,  87.59581 , 10.136151, 0),
          ...,
          ('NGTSJ225330.3+012025', 2458082.58070602,        nan,       nan, 0),
          ('NGTSJ225330.3+012025', 2458082.58085648,        nan,       nan, 0),
          ('NGTSJ225330.3+012025', 2458082.58099537,        nan,       nan, 0)],
         dtype=(numpy.record, [('SOURCE_ID', 'S20'), ('HJD', '>f8'), ('SYSFLUX', '>f4'), ('FLUX_ERR', '>f4'), ('FLAG', '>i4')]))
```

Ideally I would like to do this with a quick query as these files in my real dataset are so large that I would like to avoid vstacking and using where statements if I can.

Things I have tried:

```
f[1].data['SOURCE_ID'=='NGTSJ225445.7+014958']
```

... returns:

```
FITS_rec([], shape=(0, 25603520),
     dtype=(numpy.record, [('SOURCE_ID', 'S20'), ('HJD', '>f8'), ('SYSFLUX', '>f4'), ('FLUX_ERR', '>f4'), ('FLAG', '>i4')]))
```

and...

```
f[1].data['SYSFLUX'][np.array(f[1].data['SOURCE_ID']) == 'NGTSJ225342.6+015412']
```

...works, but seems non-optimal.

---

Related package imports:

```
from astropy.io import fits
```

---

Apologies for not being able to provide a more concise and reproducable test script for this. I'm actually not sure how to create the 1D list like .fits record with a mix of strings, floats and intigers like the file I'm working with.

Comment: You can do this: `table = f[1].data; table['SYSFLUX'][table['SOURCE_ID'] == 'NGTSJ225342.6+015412']` sort of like your second example but simpler. Or if you want all columns, `table[table['SOURCE_ID'] == 'NGTSJ225342.6+015412']` This is the normal way to query tabular data in Numpy.  You might also find the [`astropy.table`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/) interface a bit nicer for more complex queries.

Comment: in the case of `f[1].data['SOURCE_ID'=='NGTSJ225445.7+014958']` here you're just comparing the strings `'SOURCE_ID'` and `'NGTSJ225445.7+014958'` which returns `False`, which is equivalent to `0` so you're just returning the first row.

Comment: Thanks, these are really useful! I found that using QTable in the astropy.table link you sent is really neat and tidy actually. If you use `t = astropy.table.QTable(f[1].data)`, it makes it even cleaner to query by using `t[t['SOURCE_ID'] == 'NGTSJ225133.3+015255']`. And it's not very slow either. Thanks for the help @Iguananaut! :)